# DynamoDB single-active cross region replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database-replication

I'm trying to understand DynamoDB replication & failover strategies but do not find any articles on the web which clarifies them. I understand cross-region replication can be achieved by DynamoDB with Global Tables but I also understand this is a multi-active table setup, meaning there are multiple active tables and multiple replica table. Is there a setup with single-active table and multiple replicas? I briefly read about this in [this](https://jayendrapatil.com/aws-dynamodb-advanced/#DynamoDB_Cross-region_Replication) article but do not find any mentions anywhere else including AWS documentation.

I'm also trying to understand failover strategies for both cases - Is there a DynamoDB Java Client which can failover across AZs in case of issues in one AZ for both reads & writes?

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB Global Tables are always active-active but you can treat it as active-passive if you prefer. Many people do. That's useful if you want to use features like condition expressions, transactions, or do any non-idempotent wheres where you could have the same item being written around the same time in both regions with the second write happening before the first replicates, because this would cause the first write to be effectively lost.

To do this you just route your write traffic to one region, and to failover you decide when it's time to write to another. The failover region is always happy to be an active region if you'll let it.

As for AZs, DynamoDB is a regional service meaning it crosses at least 3 AZs always and would keep operating fine even if a full AZ were to be down. You don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Does this mean that the AWS SDK we use to connect to DynamoDB would be able to failover among the AZs and we don't have to redirect ourselves?

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you didn’t put all your calling clients in one AZ :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a setup with single-active table and multiple replicas

Unfortunately there is no such single active and multiple replica setup for cross region in dynamodb using global tables, so failover strategy will be for multiple active tables and multiple replica tables! - Source - [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/global-tables/#How_it_works)

Fro failover strategies

[According to docs](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/global-tables/#Benefits)

> If a single AWS Region becomes isolated or degraded, your application can redirect to a different Region and perform reads and writes against a different replica table.

This means this is seamingless smooth process which happends by default ofcourse you can add custom logic when to redirect

Comment: I did see this document, but the quoted text says `your application can redirect` which mean we always have to handle the logic to route to redirect, right?

Comment: In my view `An application can read and write data to any replica table. If your application only uses eventually consistent reads and only issues reads against one AWS Region, it will work without any modification.``You can apply custom business logic to determine when to redirect requests to other Regions.` This happends automatically, but if you want to control that you can do that using custom logic